# if true then false... if false then false?

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, graphql

i am building a to do app, onclick i want "if true to be false" and "if false to be true".

i am using graphql, before start using it everything were working with the same logic i used now..
so why wouldn't now ???

```
    updatedTask: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const id = args.id
      const task = await client.get({
        index: 'tasks',
        id: id
      });

      if(task.done){
      await client.update({
          index: 'tasks',
          id: id,
          body: {
            doc: {
              done: false
            }
          }
        });
      }else{
        await client.update({
          index: 'tasks',
          id: id,
          body: {
            doc: {
              done: true
            }
          }
        });
      }
    },
```

here the full schema

```
    const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
const { resolvers } = require('./resolvers');

const typeDefs = `#graphql

    type Query {
        tasks: [Task!]!
    } 

    type Mutation{
        newTask( input: taskInput!): Task
        updatedTask( id: ID!): Task
        deletedTask( id: ID!): Task
    }

    input taskInput{
        name: String!,
    }

    type Task {
        name: String!
        done: Boolean!
        id: ID!
    }
`
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
module.exports = {schema}
```

and here the resolvers, i changed as suggested in the comment and i used `!task.done` but still the same issue

```
const { client } = require('./controllers/tasks');

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    tasks: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const result = await client.search({
        index: 'tasks',
        body: {
          query: {
            match_all: {}
          }
        }
      });
      const tasks = result.hits.hits.map((hit) => hit._source);
      return tasks
    }
  },

  Mutation: {
    
    deletedTask: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const id = args.id
      await client.delete({
        index: 'tasks',
        id: id,
      });
    },


    updatedTask: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const id = args.id
      const task = await client.get({
        index: 'tasks',
        id: id
      });
      console.log(task.done)
      await client.update({
          index: 'tasks',
          id: id,
          body: {
            doc: {
              done: !task.done
            }
          }
        });
    },

    newTask: async (parent, args, context, info) => {  
      const { input } = args;
      const newTask = {
        name: input.name,
        done: false
      };

      const result = await client.index({             
        index: 'tasks',
        body: newTask
      });

      const { _id } = result;                               
      newTask._id = _id;

      return newTask;
    }
  }
};

module.exports = { resolvers };
```

Comment: `done: !task.done` is an easy way to toggle.

Comment: What is the actual behaviour that you are observing?  Can you describe, in detail, the undesirable/unexpected things that happen when you run your code?

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple `updatedTask`'s in flight at the same time?

Comment: @Wyck simply if it is false and i move to true it get stuck and cannot go back to false

Comment: I'd start by adding `console.log(task)` after your `const task = await ...` to see if `task` and `task.done` are what you think they are.

Comment: if i console log task
i get the last task i choose and all the correct metadata
if i console log task.done 
i get undefined

Comment: @anfield: *"if i console log task.done i get undefined"* - Then it's `undefined`, which is "falsy", so the value would **always** be set to `true` in this logic.  Can you provide information about why `task.done` **shouldn't** be `undefined`?

Comment: @David sorry i am not sure what information you want.. my source code is here..
i m gonna try to send both schema and resolvers in a sec

Comment: @David i posted the full source code

Comment: @anfield: Well, if the problem is server-side or otherwise part of the GraphQL implementation then that sounds like it may be out of scope for the question above.  If the returned object has no `done` property then you can use that observation to start debugging the code which builds and returns that object, as up until now you've been under the assumption that it *does* have that property.

Comment: @anfield: I'm not super familiar with GraphQL syntax, but... Are you fetching a "task" or an *array* of "tasks"?

Comment: @David fetching an array 
and i'm updating just one task by checking the ID.

Comment: @David i just do not understand how is it possible that the "DONE" parameter is undefined ... if can find the task by the ID it mean it also must have all the properties such as _id, name, done !!

Comment: @anfield: *"fetching an array"* - Then is `task` an array?  If so then (1) it is poorly named and you've confused yourself with that name, and (2) an array indeed has no property called `done`.

Comment: @David My bad ! i am sorry, 
the `task` you see in the `resolvers.js` is just one task that i'm getting with `client.get` so it should have the property of done!

infact when i console log `task` i confirm that i see all the property such as 
_id name done !!!!

Comment: @anfield: How have you confirmed that it's not an array?  Which resolver is being used to return that data?

Comment: @David i can confirm that is not an array by using `console.log(task)`
and i get all the metadata and properties such as "name" "done" "_ID"

Comment: @David i am working on "updateTask" if is this what are you asking for

Comment: @anfield: *"and i get all the metadata and properties such as "name" "done" "_ID""* - Please be specific.  What **exactly** does it output?  Simply assuming that your debugging observations must be correct and don't need to be included in the question is counterproductive, as you wouldn't be asking if what you were doing was correct.

Comment: @anfield: *"i am working on "updateTask""* - Do you mean `updatedTask`?  So `const task = await client.get({` invokes the code in the `updatedTask` resolver?  It sounds like your naming is **very** confusing for these objects and operations then, which is likely the cause of the bug.  If this is not the case, please narrow the focus to the **specific** operation which isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: @David yes i am working on `updatedTask` ... `const task await client.get()` i need it to get all the data from the task that match `id:id`, once i got it i can update every parameter using `client.update` in this case i am updating `done:!done` but it works just once! if i want to go back to false i cannot it get stuck on true

Comment: @David this is all the data i receive by doing console.log(task)

{
  _index: 'tasks',
  _id: '3ipY2YgB-0wwWwxO2aWF',
  _version: 2,
  _seq_no: 27,
  _primary_term: 1,
  found: true,
  _source: { name: 'learn this stuff2', done: true }
}

Comment: @anfield: I'm afraid the information you're providing is very confusing.  You call `const task = await client.get({` inside of `updatedTask`, and now you claim that operation itself also calls `updatedTask`?  How would that not be an infinitely recursive operation?  *"this is all the data i receive"* - Well, that object indeed has no `done` property.  What is **does** have is a `_source` property which itself has a `done` property.

Comment: @anfield: Overall it sounds like the core problem here is that you're very confused about what operations you are performing and what data you have.  We can sympathize that you're struggling, but now is a good time for you to simplify what you're doing, carefully name your operations/objects/etc., and carefully debug each operation and observe its result.  The question (and this comment thread) are just too all over the place.

Comment: @David yes i just realize it doesn't have any `done` property 
i tried with `done: !task._source.done`but still not working

anyways i know it look confusing but is the only way to get access to specific data on elasticsearch, you need to find the task you want with `.get` then you can `.update` at least this is how i learned..

Comment: @David thank you so much i solved with `done: !task._source.done`
i am new to stackoverflow i don't know how to pin your comments but thx again for the pacience !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

i don't know about graphql, but if you just want to negate a value you can do !value:

```
  updatedTask: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const id = args.id
      const task = await client.get({
        index: 'tasks',
        id: id
      });

      
      await client.update({
          index: 'tasks',
          id: id,
          body: {
            doc: {
              done: ! task.done
            }
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: i tried but also in your way it doesn't work.. so weird

Comment: have you tried console.log(task.done)? what is the output?

Comment: damn it is undefined !!! 
how am i gonna do to see if task is done or not

Comment: if i console.log(task) i get the task i selected and all the metadata also i can see done: true

Comment: the .done may be inside other object, like this: task.whatever.done

Answer (score 0):

thx to @David
i understood i never had a done property
what i was looking for was inside _source.done !

solved with a `!task._source.done`